# Executing a cursor

Tags: php, oracle

I can't execute the stored procedure from the function. Here is what I try:

```
function STD( $i_std_id, $i_order_by   )
{

        $conn = open_db("CONN");
        $outrefc  = oci_new_cursor($conn); //Declare cursor variable
        $mycursor = oci_parse ($conn, "begin  TEST.STD( :i_std_id, :i_order_by, :curs); end;"); // prepare procedure call

        oci_bind_by_name($mycursor,':i_std_id'  , $i_std_id   );
        oci_bind_by_name($mycursor,':i_order_by', $i_order_by );
        oci_bind_by_name($mycursor,':curs'      , $outrefc, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR); // bind procedure parameters


        return exec_cur($conn, $mycursor, $outrefc);

}
```

Connection is ok. Anyhow I get no result. I'm expecting more rows.

I can print the parameters with  `echo $i_order_by."#### $i_std_id"`. 
When I run the procedure directly  in DB with the printed parameters, I get the output.

Here is the signature:

```
PROCEDURE STD
(
    i_std_id     IN NUMBER,
    i_qot_id     IN NUMBER,
    i_order_by   IN VARCHAR,
    o_recordset  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
);
```

Any clue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't there a problem with the parameters ? I can see you call procedure `STD` with 3 parameters, whereas you mention 4 in its signature (`i_qot_id` seems to be the extra one).

Comment: i_qot_id should be null.

Comment: Whatever its value, it should be present: calling `STD(a, b, c, d)` is not the same as calling `STD(a, c, d)` !